# Write GeoPandas df to PostGIS - Linestring Z geometry

Tags: python, geopandas, well-known-text, geodataframe

I am trying to write a geodataframe with *Linestring Z* geometry to a PostGIS table.

This rise the error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'LineString'
[SQL: INSERT INTO test (geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromEWKT(%(geom)s))]
```

Command

```
gdf.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False,
       dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='LINESTRINGZ', srid='32633',dimension='3')})
```

The geometry was created with

```
df['geom'] = df['geom'].apply(wkt.loads)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geom')
```

and this is the head

```
                                                geom
0  LINESTRING Z (272353.39 7040567.82 98.48, 2723...
```

I dont know what is failing. I though it was because my features has Z value. But from postgis doc about ST_GeomFromEWKT" *This function supports 3d and will not drop the z-index".*